# How does webpack pick a relative path inside node_modules ? does it reference package.json at all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When i do `npm install react-slick`, i get the following in my `node_modules` folder:

[image]

Now in my react application in a `src/index.js` file, when i do the following:

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
```

How does webpack know where to pick slider from ? will it at all look for some clue or definition inside `node_modules/react-slick/package.json` at all ?

**Edit** :- so here is the [package.json](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/package.json) file for webpack, when i import Slider from 'react-slick' , does it resolve to `dist` or `lib` ? and which file does it pick then and why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the simple walkthrough of it will be as below:

### Simple Walkthrough

If you carefully look at the `node_modules/react-slick/package.json` there is a property named `main`. Something like this:

```json
{
  "name": "react-slick",
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

It will tell the Webpack which file is the entry file of the whole package *(It's usually referred to `index.js`)*. All the necessary exports for the package lies in this file, so Webpack will only look for those exports and will import what you looking for. In this particular case, there should be a default export for the `Slider` that you using right now. So the `index.js` is probably something like this:

```js
// index.js
var slider = require('./lib/slider'); // Usually all the main modules are lies under lib folder.
// other imports ...
module.exports = slider;
```

### Difference between `lib` and `dist`

Usually, the `dist` folder is for shipping a UMD that a user can use if they aren't using package management. The `lib` folder is what `package.json`, `main` property points to, and users that install your package using `npm` will consume that directly. The only use of the `lib` as opposed to `src` is to transform your source using babel and Webpack to be more generally compatible since most build processes don't run babel transforms on packages in `node_modules`.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Well, actually you referring to the master branch and it will work differently from the latest package release, you should look at [the latest release](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/v0.3.1/package.json) of the package which is available under the tags. Then you can see everything is like as I said.

Comment: The answer to your edited part of the question is in SMAKSS's answer, the package.json is defining a `"main": "./lib"`. Which is the answer to where it will target once it reaches the folder.

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac sorry to be a bit of a prick , but `./lib` is a directory not a file name so once webpack is in `./lib` how does it pickup `index.js` as the file to find slider in ? what if there is no index.js , is it like how node evaluates , eg. look for a index.js file , if not look for some other file etc ?

Comment: @SMAKSS the file you linked to actually has `main` set to index.jsx, which i think is an extension not used in this pakage, to get to the root of it , if i `npm install react-slick` , go to `node_modules/react-slick/package.json`, the main is still `./lib` .. hope this information is relevant :)

Comment: @SMAKSS, thanks for the edited answer, if you can just add info about how webpack picks only the index.js file inside the `./lib` directory , which i think it does for all directories irrespective of it being node_modules or not , i'll accept your answer , if not i'll accept it tomorrow anyway :) thanks again

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Well, I'm not sure how this package wrote exactly in production mode, but I add the necessary information about packages in general. But if as you said the main points to `./lib` the Webpack will look for an `index.js` into it and then there should be a default export for slider in that `index.js`

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Thank you. About how Webpack looks for an `index.js` in any directory, I have to say in the meantime it is beyond my understanding *(how its exactly work under the hood)* but due to its default setting, if you provide a directory for it, firstly it will look for an index file into it and if it finds it, it will return the default and other exports of it, otherwise it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack uses [aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to target `node_modules` using a shorthand.

### Example #1:

```
import 'xyz'
/abc/node_modules/xyz/index.js
```

### Example #2:

```
import 'xyz/file.js'
/abc/node_modules/xyz/file.js
```

Once it targets the correct folder in `node_modules`, it follows the rules written in the package itself (`manifest`, `package.json`)

You can also define your own aliases as such:

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      xyz$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/file.js')
    }
  }
};
```

And then can be used as `import xyz from $xyz`